# RegisterStartupScript shows message after function ends

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

i want to show a javascript confirm box on the client side under OnChange event "chkIsActive_CheckedChanged". i am using registerStartupscript int the code behind for this purpose. this confirm message is displaying fine but it is displaying after end of the event "chkIsActive_CheckedChanged". i want to display the confirm message while executing in the function. Please help me out.

My HTML

```
 <asp:CheckBox ID="lbl_IsActive" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="chkIsActive_CheckedChanged"  AutoPostBack="true" Checked='<%# Eval("IsActive") %>' ></asp:CheckBox>
```

My javascript

```
  <script type = "text/javascript">
       function Confirm() {
           var confirm_value = document.getElementById("<%=IsChecked.ClientID%>");

           if (confirm("Do you want to save data?")) {
               confirm_value.value = "1";
           } else {
               confirm_value.value = "0";
           }

       }
    </script>
```

my C# code behind

```
 protected void chkIsActive_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.GetType(), "MyFun1", "Confirm();", true);

            string confirmValue = IsChecked.Value;
            if (confirmValue == "1")
            {
                string CarEstimateID = "";

                Entities.CarEstimateFirms ObjEst = new Entities.CarEstimateFirms();

                CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)sender;
                GridViewRow gr = (GridViewRow)chk.Parent.Parent;
                CarEstimateID = (GridView1.Rows[gr.RowIndex].FindControl("lbl_CarEstimateFirmID") as Label).Text;   // GridView1.DataKeys[gr.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

                ObjEst.CarEstimateFirmID = Convert.ToInt32(CarEstimateID);
                ObjEst.IsActive = chk.Checked;

                BLL.Common.UpdateCarEstimateFirms(ObjEst);

                BindGridView();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `onchange` javascript event in your checkbox:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="lbl_IsActive" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="chkIsActive_CheckedChanged"  AutoPostBack="true"
    Checked='<%# Eval("IsActive") %>' onchange="javascript:return Confirm();" ></asp:CheckBox>
```

Your javascript `confirm` method should be like below:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function Confirm() {
       if (confirm("Do you want to save data?")) {
           return true;
       } else {
           return false;
       }
    }
</script>
```

And remove below line from `chkIsActive_CheckedChanged` event from code behind:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.GetType(), "MyFun1", "Confirm();", true);
```